# How to list data store in gcp "Search and Conversation"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to find a way to list all data stores created within "Search and Conversation" using GCP Python client lib.
For example (image below), I currently have 2 data stores `test1-datastore` and `test2` created and I want to find the Python code to list them.
[image]

However, I did not find the Python code to do it, the seemingly correct answer I found by using REST API can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha/projects.locations.dataStores/list). Please tell me how to do this in Python.

Comment: Hi @Rui, Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/create-data-store-es) will help you for find the code ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not what I want to do, I am trying to find a API to list data stores instead of create a datastore

Comment: Can you check this [Git Hub link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python#google-cloud-python-client). I hope it will help you?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using DataStoreServiceClient v1 alpha using [list_data_store](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/discoveryengine/latest/google.cloud.discoveryengine_v1alpha.services.data_store_service.DataStoreServiceClient#google_cloud_discoveryengine_v1alpha_services_data_store_service_DataStoreServiceClient_list_data_stores)?